# Confused about Matching vs Perfect Matching?

Tags: math, graph, graph-theory

My T.A. defined a Matching as an independent set of vertices (meaning there are no common edges between them). I'm a bit confused about that as I thought that was an independent set, while a Matching was the same thing as an independent edge set?

Additionally, I'm confused about the difference between a Matching and a Perfect Matching. According to the book Applied Combinatorics, [This is the definition of a Matching with a companion Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfaXr.png)

According to the definition of an independent edge set, I thought it could just be {Ac, Dd} and that would constitute an independent edge set / Matching, while there a Perfect Matching does not exist.

Could someone please explain where I'm going wrong? Thanks guys!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **math** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that a matching is simply a set of independent edges. Your example of {Ac, Dd} is indeed a matching. In the prompt that you've included, the reference to "perfect matching" is far from explicit (emphasis added):

> The problem is to find a feasible **one-to-one** matching of people to jobs, or to show that no **such** matching can exist.

This excerpt requires you to go through a communication barrier since they forego some pedantry for conciseness. See for instance their description of a bipartite graph:

> .. graphs in which all the edges go *horizontally* between two sets of vertices ..

In your case, since one may not be as interested in *applying* (as in the name of the book) a non-perfect matching, all matching problems included may implicitly be referring to perfect matching (or at least a maximal one).

As for your T.A., if he/she didn't explicitly said "meaning there are no common edges between them", then it's most likely just a communication error. He/she may just be thinking of *pairs* of vertices, but the speech didn't come out right.
We can only speculate here, so I suggest simply going to him/her and talk about it. You can easily come up with a counterexample in any case (e.g., using the same graph from the excerpt, the independent set {A, a} is not a matching).

---

**Edit**
From James' comment, the question should be post/migrate to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/). I don't have any rights to do those things at this moment.

Comment: Brilliant Answer. Cleared up all my questions. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yeah, I don't have the reputation to upvote yet. I accepted the best answer though. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Just got my right to upvote your question :)